# Passing variables in Json

Tags: json, matlab, firebase-realtime-database

I have an android app to which I have to pass the results from MATLAB (via firebase). As JSON format is required, I used the following command:

```
Firebase_Url = 'https://***.firebaseio.com/***.json';
webwrite(Firebase_Url, '{ "HR": "app.HR", "HRV": "app.hrv"}');
```

But the problem is - app.HR and app.hrv are variables containing the values.

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You may want to provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that one could actually see what is inside those two variables. From the case here, I have to guess: use `strcat` and the content of `app.HR` (if it is a cell `app.HR`{:}`, if it is string, you have no problem, if it is a number use `num2str`...)

Answer (score 1):

then convert them to a single string using concatenation or formatted printing.

```
webwrite(Firebase_Url, sprintf('{ "HR": "%s", "HRV": "%s"}',app.HR,app.hrv));
```